Draw route on Mapbox Maps from two points. (Latest Mapbox v3.4.0 and Mapbox Mapsv 11)
I need to add a route to a Storyboard NavigationMapView!. This should just show the route and not activate turn by turn navigation.
    func calculateRoute(from Origin: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to Destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        let origin = Waypoint(coordinate: Origin, coordinateAccuracy: -1, name: "Start")
        let destination = Waypoint(coordinate: Destination, coordinateAccuracy: -1, name: "Finish")
        let routeOptions = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination], profileIdentifier: .automobileAvoidingTraffic)
        self.showRouteLoader()
        Directions.shared.calculate(routeOptions) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.hideRouteLoader()
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    BreadcrumbsManager.sharedInstance.logcustomBreadcrumb(message: error.localizedDescription, category: "MapBoxFailed")
                    self.showErrorMessage(error.localizedDescription)
                case .success(let response):
                    guard let route = response.routes?.first else { return }
                    self.route = route
                    self.routes = response.routes
                    self.routeOptions = routeOptions
                    self.NavMapView.mapView
                    // Showcase the route and destination waypoint, and set camera
                    var navigationRoutes: NavigationRoutes
                    let navigationProvider = MapboxNavigationProvider(coreConfig: CoreConfig())
                    let mapboxNavigationProvider = MapboxNavigationProvider(coreConfig: .init())
                    let mapboxNavigation = navigationProvider.mapboxNavigation
                    let routingProvider = mapboxNavigation.routingProvider()
                    let navigationRoutes = routingProvider.calculateRoutes(options: routeOptions).value {}
                    self.NavMapView.showcase(navigationRoutes, animated: true)
                    let coordinates = route.shape?.coordinates ?? []
                    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 405, right: 50)
                    let camera = self.NavMapView.mapView.mapboxMap.camera(for: coordinates, padding: insets, bearing: nil, pitch: nil)
                    self.cameraRouteAnimation(from: Origin, to: Destination)
                }
            }
        }
    }

@IBOutlet var NavMapView: NavigationMapView!

The code where I am trying to showcase the generated route on the Mapview , trying to use the latest spm version (Latest Mapbox v3.4.0 and Mapbox Mapsv 11)
